# cookie associated with a cross-site resource at <URL> was set without the `SameSite` attribute when submitting a form

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, cross-domain

I have a worldpay form on a client website and it won't work on ipads without disabling an **prevent cross-site tracking** on safari.
It seems to be related to cross site cookies.

The form looks like this:

```
<div class="d-none">
    <form action="https://secure.worldpay.com/wcc/purchase" target="payment-iframe" method="post" id="worldpayForm">
        <input type="hidden" id="instId" name="instId">
        <input type="hidden" id="cartId" name="cartId">
        <input type="hidden" id="amount" name="amount">
        <input type="hidden" id="currency" name="currency">
        <input type="submit" id="makePayment" value="Buy This ">
    </form>
</div>

<iframe name="payment-iframe" style="min-width: 760px; min-height: 450px; border: 0;"></iframe>
```

In the JavaScript there is a line that does this:

```
$('#worldpayForm').submit();
```

If I comment out that line, I don't get the chrome warning. 
I read somewhere you can add this:

```
response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=Strict");
```

But that appears to be only talking about making requests to other domains. How can I apply that in my case?

Comment: Can you provide some more information?
What option do you need to disable in Safari?
Do you know which cookie is being affected? Is it one for `worldpay.com` or for your domain?
You can try looking at https://web.dev/samesite-cookie-recipes to see if you recognise your use case.

Comment: updated my question and added the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this. It was, I did have my own cookie solution already:

```
export function getCookie(name) {
    var i, x, y;
    const arCookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (i = 0; i < arCookies.length; i++) {
        x = arCookies[i].substr(0, arCookies[i].indexOf('='));
        y = arCookies[i].substr(arCookies[i].indexOf('=') + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
        if (x === name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
    return '';
}

export function setCookie(name, value, expiresInDays) {
    const expiryDate = new Date();
    expiryDate.setDate(expiryDate.getDate() + expiresInDays);
    const cookieValue = escape(value) + (expiresInDays === null ? '' : `; expires=${expiryDate.toUTCString()}`);
    document.cookie = `${name}=${cookieValue}`;
}

export function clearCookies() {
    const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');

    for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        const cookie = cookies[i];
        const eqPos = cookie.indexOf('=');
        const name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = `${name}=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;`;
    }
}
```

I just updated it to this:

```
export function getCookie(name) {
    var i, x, y;
    const arCookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (i = 0; i < arCookies.length; i++) {
        x = arCookies[i].substr(0, arCookies[i].indexOf('='));
        y = arCookies[i].substr(arCookies[i].indexOf('=') + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
        if (x === name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
    return '';
}

export function setCookie(name, value, expiresInDays) {
    const expiryDate = new Date();
    expiryDate.setDate(expiryDate.getDate() + expiresInDays);
    const cookieValue = escape(value) + (expiresInDays === null ? '' : `; expires=${expiryDate.toUTCString()}`);
    document.cookie = `${name}=${cookieValue};SameSite=Strict;secure`;
}

export function clearCookies() {
    const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');

    for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        const cookie = cookies[i];
        const eqPos = cookie.indexOf('=');
        const name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = `${name}=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;SameSite=Strict;secure`;
    }
}
```

And it all works now.